# if statement doesn't work properly in python

Tags: python, list, if-statement

```
d={1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'a', 5:'d', 6:'e', 7:'a', 8:'b'}
value = raw_input("Choose a value to be searched: ")
data = ""
    if value in d:
         data = d.keys["value"]
         print(data)
    else:
          print "There isn't such value in the dictionary"
```

So I write 'a' and I want to get the key '1'
but it skips "data = d.keys["value"] print(data)" and it prints me the message of "else"

What have I done wrong?

Comment: ```in``` checks for keys, not values. (and there are additional problems like ```d.keys["value"]``` as a string ```"value"``` is not an object ```value```)

Answer (score 2):

Containment checks for `dict` check the keys, not the values, and `'a'` is a value in the `dict`, not a key.

The simplest fix would be to change your test to:

```
if value in d.viewvalues():  # d.values() on Python 3
```

but that's still sub-optimal; you can't perform efficient (`O(1)`) lookups in the values of a `dict` (nor can you do `d.keys[value]` as you seem to think you can; you'd have to perform a second linear scan to find the key, or perform a more complicated single scan to determine if the value exists and pull the key at the same time).

Really though, it seems like you want your dictionary reversed, with the keys as values and vice-versa. Doing it this way:

```
d = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'a', 5:'d', 6:'e', 7:'a', 8:'b'}
d_inv = {v: k for k, v in d.items()}  # Make inverted version of d
value = raw_input("Choose a value to be searched: ")
if value in d_inv:
    data = d_inv[value]
    print(data)
else:
    print "There isn't such value in the dictionary"
```

you can perform the containment check and lookup efficiently (if `d` isn't otherwise needed, you can just replace `d` with the same structure as `d_inv` and use `d` instead of `d_inv` uniformly).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Yeah, editing error. I initially made `d.values()` the "default" version, with `d.viewvalues()` in the comment, then noticed while typing that the OP was on Py2, and flipped the primary example with the comment, but forgot to fix the version info. :-) Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
d={1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'a', 5:'d', 6:'e', 7:'a', 8:'b'}
value = 'q'
data = [key for key, val in d.items() if val == value]

if len(data) > 0:
    print(data)
else:
    print "There isn't such value in the dictionary"
```

Then you would get the results

[1, 4, 7]

Answer (score 0):

As stated, you need the value, here's an alternative

```
if any(d[value] for value in d):
```

Then, `d.keys["value"]` is actually `d[value]`